# Cast function in SQL server

Tags: sql-server

Sample data:

```
1) 0.02500 = 25
2) 1.0000=100
```

I tried below code but it's converting 0.25 to 30

```
Select Try_cast(workcountry as decimal (10,2)*100
```

Answer (score 1):

Multiply first, then cast. This should give you your an expected behavior.

```
SELECT TRY_CAST(0.02500*100 AS decimal(10,2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the rounding, 0.025 with 2 decimal places rounds to 0.03.  You then multiply that by 100 to get 3.  Add an extra decimal place and you'll be fine

```
select try_cast(0.02500 as decimal (10,3)) * 100
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
declare @workcountry float = 0.025;

select try_cast(@workcountry * 100. as decimal (10,2))
```

Comment: For 0.025000 it's giving 0.0

Comment: @Jacob use decimal instead of float